# I have a matter with calling function (check_number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

this code for validation phone number but it 's not working
after testing and trying I found that the problem is in calling the function  (check_number) 
can any one help me 
and if any one have any suggestion to make validation easier than that kindly tell me 
THANK YOU

```js
$(function () {
 $("#error_number").hide();
 var error_number = false;
 $("#form_number").blur(function(){
  check_number();
  console.log("dsa")
 });
 function check_number() {
  var number_length = $("#form_number").val().length;
   
  if (number_length != 11) {
   console.log("hello")
   $("#error_number").html("the number must be 11 digit");
   $("#error_number").show();
   $("#form_number").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
   error_nubmer = true;
  } else {
   console.log("hell")
   $("#error_number").hide();
   $("#form_number").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
   }
  }

 $("#myForm").submit(function() {
   error_number = false;

   check_number();
  
   if (error_fname === false ) {
     alert("Sent Successfull");
     return true;
    } else {
     alert("Please Fill the form Correctly");
     return false;
   }
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group" >
  <label for="exampleInputnumber2">Mobile     number</label>
  <input minlength="11" maxlength="11" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" id="form_number" placeholder="01234567890" required="required">
  <span class="the-message">Please fill this feild</span> <span id="error_number"> Please enter a correct phone number</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use jquery validation plugin or something like that https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: Can you tell what is the error in the validation ?

Comment: Can you define "*not working*"? **What** isn't working? Does it trigger but not validate? Does it not trigger at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not getting called because you have 2 ids to your input field

`<input minlength="11" maxlength="11" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" id="form_number" placeholder="01234567890" required="required">` . Remove one and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you are trying to initialize a global variable but the global variable is inside the script function it should be outside globally

```
<script>
var error_number= false
$(function(){
//rest of your code
})
```

now its a bad practice to create unwanted or not needed global var due to many reasons what i recomend would be

```
$(function () {
    $("#error_number").hide(); 
    $("#form_number").blur(function(){
        var error = check_number();
        console.log("dsa")
    });
    function check_number() {
        var number_length = $("#form_number").val().length;

        if (number_length != 11) {
            console.log("hello")
            $("#error_number").html("the number must be 11 digit");
            $("#error_number").show();
            $("#form_number").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
             return true;
        } else {
            console.log("hell")
            $("#error_number").hide();
            $("#form_number").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
            return false;
            }
        }

    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
      error_number = check_number(); 
      if (error_number === false ) {
        alert("Sent Successfull");
        return true;
       } else {
        alert("Please Fill the form Correctly");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
```

since you want to have your custom validator this code might help but there are plenty of good validator plugins out there more then that html 5 validation control should be enough for simple validations